# Perl claims uninitialized value on a variable that was set from an array

Tags: perl

I'm not sure why its doing this, but it is. I have a project i'm working on for keeping score, and saving it to text/data files. it also will show information saved in a file, and a few other goodies. Right now, i have a set of code that i'm trying to get working. I have the file set so that it automatically runs a certain sub, but i'm trying to trigger the sub that shows data. I run the script using `perl scorecard.pl --display-file scores.dat`, and i get the following:

```
    Use of uninitialized value $gn in print at scorecard.pl line 30.
    Use of uninitialized value $gt in print at scorecard.pl line 30.
    Use of uninitialized value $gp in print at scorecard.pl line 30.
    Game '' was started  with  players.
    these were the scores:
    Use of uninitialized value $gp in numeric lt (<) at scorecard.pl line 31.
    Died at scorecard.pl line 35.
    Welcome to scorecard
    A simple scorecard script

    What game would you like to score?
    ^C
```

Here's the code for the display sub:

```
    sub dispfile()
    {
        my ($opt_name, $dfile) = @_;
        open (my $fhd,'<',$dfile)
         or die "Could not open file '",$dfile,"'.\n";
        chomp(my @ls = <$fhd>);
        my $gt = $ls[0];
        my $gn = $ls[1];
        my $gp = $ls[2];
        print "Game '",$gn,"' was started ",$gt," with ",$gp," players.\nthese were the scores:\n";
        for(my $i=3;$i<$gp;$i++){
            print $ls[$i];
            }
        close $fhd;
        die;
        }
```

The whole project is currently on my github, and i have pushed the latest version to my dev-0.1-r2 branch: [GitHub - scorecard.pl](https://github.com/rvzm/scorecard/blob/dev-0.1-r2/scorecard.pl)

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Perl 5.22.1 in WSL

Comment: Is the file you're reading from empty?

Comment: @Shawn it was, actually. Thank you. It turns out that updating the files on the vm from my laptop was overwriting the one I had generated (and was using), so I'm adding a `dev` argument through getopt to generate stock files. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions on your code.

You should check whether you've opened an empty file and take appropriate action:

```
chomp(my @ls = <$fhd>);
die "No data in file $dfile\n" unless @ls;
```

You can use list assignment simplify the next line:

```
my ($gt, $gn, $gp) = @ls;
```

You can use string interpolation to simplify your `print()` line:

```
print "Game '$gn' was started $gt with $gp players.\nthese were the scores:\n";
```

A `foreach` loop is usually far easier to understand than a C-style `for` loop.

```
foreach (3 .. $#ls) {
  print $ls[$_];
}
```

You can simplify that even more by iterating over array elements rather than array indexes.

```
foreach (@ls[3 .. $#ls]) {
  print $_;
}
```

Or perhaps rewrite it using the postfix version of the loop.

```
print foreach @ls[3 .. $#ls];
```

And, finally, if you want to exit your program in completely normal circumstances, then use `exit` instead of `die`.

The first of these suggestions will solve the problem that you're having.